# DataTables with colspan, Warning: Requested unknown parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I have a View which renders the model in a table. I'm using Razor to display the table when the page first loads.

I want to use the DataTables.net plugin to apply sorting and create filtering of my own. I apply the plugin as so:

```
var researchTable = $("#research-docs").DataTable({});
```

When the page loads I get a modal error:

[image: Error]

I researched this and it seems to indicate that I haven't got the right number of columns or there is a mismatch between the data I am rendering against the columns that are being returned.

My Razor code:

```
 <table id="research-docs" class="table table-hover table-striped table-library-research">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th width="250">Title</th>
        <th>Sector</th>
        <th>Analyst</th>
        <th width="70">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var research in Model.Research)
    {
        <tr class="clickable">
            <td>@research.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yy")</td>
            <td><strong>@research.Title</strong><br>@research.SubTitle</td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var sector in research.Sectors)
                {
                    <a href="/sector/@sector.SectorId">@sector.Name</a>
                }
            </td>

            <td>
                @foreach (var analyst in research.Analysts)
                {
                    <a href="/analyst/@analyst.AnalystId">@analyst.Name</a><br>
                }
            </td>
            <td><span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span> <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="4">@research.Body</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

The only thing that I think it could be is that I have a collapsed row which is supposed to appear if you click on the plus icon (i.e. where it will display @research.Body). DataTables.net doesn't seem to like rows which use colspan. Maybe.

I also thought it might be better to define the data I want to show explicitly:

```
var researchTable = $("#research-docs").DataTable({
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Date" },
        { "data": "Title" },
        { "data": "sector.Name" },
        { "data": "analyst.Name" },
        {
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null
        }
    ],
    "order": [[0, 'desc']]
});
```

This resulted in an error indicating my code (where the Sector Name I retrieve for each sector) is incorrect:

[image: Datatables.net error JSON not correct]

How can I get the plugin to work when the page first loads? I understand I will have to hook up some Ajax to apply filtering later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking further into DataTables.NET and the first error I get is because:

> There is a colspan or rowspan in the tbody of the table, which is not
>   supported by DataTables.

This supports in the theory I made in the original question (Gyrocode.com also backed this up in his answer). Allan (author of DataTables.NET) further clarifies that there is no workaround for this and having "[such a feature would need to be embeded into DataTables core.](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/18499/can-i-ignore-the-datatables-warning-about-not-supported-rowspan-colspan)"

Which is a bummer as my code is valid HTML. Having a details row with a colspan should be catered for by the library - I'd be surprised if I was the only one who has been struggling with this.

So to get it to work I had to remove the following row from the view:

```
<tr class="collapse">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4">@research.Body</td>
</tr>
```

Instead I had to use a jQuery Ajax call to get the "Body" field I needed using the following code:

```
$('#research-docs tbody').on('click', 'td.show-body', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = researchTable.row(tr);
    var documentId = tr.attr('id');

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        var documentObjDTO = "{ 'documentId': " + documentId + "}";
        var ajaxOptions = {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/GetResearchDocBody",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: documentObjDTO
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxOptions)
            .done(function (response) {
                var bodyRow = '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td colspan="4">' + response.Research[0].Body + '</td></tr>';
                row.child(bodyRow).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            });
    }
});
```

This is a modified version of the [Child rows (show extra / detailed information](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) example. I don't like this solution but that's a limitation I'm stuck with.

Now I can move on to the filtering/searching part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that DataTables library doesn't support `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes for `<td>` elements. Alternative solution is to display row details like shown in [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html).

Also you should not use names in `columns.data` property, this is needed only for AJAX data or server-side processing. For static data zero-based indexes should be used instead.

Your initialization code should be:

```
var researchTable = $("#research-docs").DataTable({
    "columns": [
        { "data": 0 },
        { "data": 1 },
        { "data": 2 },
        { "data": 3 },
        {
            "orderable": false,
            "data": 4
        }
    ],
    "order": [0, 'desc']
});
```

or could be simplified, if you're adjusting behavior of 5th column only:

```
var researchTable = $("#research-docs").DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 4
        }
    ],
    "order": [0, 'desc']
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like "sector.Name" doesn't exist in the DOM. Have you tried removing the explicit column definitions and just initalizing the plugins like this:

```
var researchTable = $("#research-docs").DataTable({
    "order": [[0, 'desc']] });
```

You've created five columns in your  and you're populating them all from your model so explicit declaration might be overkill.

Comment: I tried that already. I highlighted that in the question at the beginning.